# Need a simple file picker - don't need an upload control

Tags: xpages

All I want to do is duplicate the notes (don't need an upload control)

```
KeyFileName = WS.OpenFileDialog(False, "Select Key file", "Workflo Systems Key File|*.wfs")
```

I simply need the filename and path and want the user to only be able to select a file with a given extension. This is a piece of cake in LS but have not been able to find a way to do this in SSJS. Found several instances of requests for this functionality but not much in how to accomplish it.

Comment: I started digging around this functionality a few months ago but never got very far.  But to the best of my knowledge, you will need to use Java Swing:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might depend on your browsers.  If they are html5 compatible then check this out:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Since XPages includes Dojo then maybe this will help there:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/form/FilePickerTextBox.html

Regardless you're going to need to do something with Client Side javaScript I'm sure.

Good Luck!

Comment: I think the problem with anything client side is browsers do not give up the full path of a file for security reasons.  Of course, if you provide the starting path and don't allow navigation away from that somehow, you can build the full path when a file is selected.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything like this but yeah I assume there's likely some security limitations in play here that aren't a factor from LotusScript inside the Notes Client.

Comment: Found this code :
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#myButton").click(function()
{
$(":file").css("background-color","Orange");
});
});
</script>
<body>
<input name="licenseKey" size="50" type="file" ></input>
</body>
</html>

and it works pretty well, would like to limit it to only return files with a specific extension. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a LS agent that does this so I'm just going to call it.